# Scraping page with drop-down menus in R

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to use the Selenium package in R to scrape the following page: http://www.wbsec.gov.in/(S(njkinc55hbv2hw55xksxdv45))/DetailedResult/Detailed_gp.aspx. I am interested in all combinations of the drop-downs selected but keep getting the

```
Couldnt connect to host on http://localhost:4444/wd/hub.Please ensure a Selenium server is running.
Error in queryRD(paste0(serverURL, "/session"), "POST", qdata = toJSON(serverOpts)) :

 library(RSelenium)
 library(XML)
 library(magrittr)

 checkForServer()
 startServer()
 remDrv<-remoteDriver()
 remDrv$open()
 remDrv$navigate("http://www.wbsec.gov.in/(S(njkinc55hbv2hw55xksxdv45))/DetailedResult/Detailed_gp.aspx")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use an intermediary such as [burpsuite](http://portswigger.net/burp/) to capture what's going on and use the results in combination with `rvest`'s `html_session` and/or `httr`'s `POST`.

In this case, you'd see your original URL contains the initial `<select>` menu and you'd also see that selecting one issues a `POST` to:

```
http://www.wbsec.gov.in/(S(njkinc55hbv2hw55xksxdv45))/DetailedResult/Detailed_gp.aspx
```

with a number of the hidden variables in the original form element as well as `ddldistrict`, `ddlblock` and `ddlgp`. The response contains the subsequent `<select>` menu options.

Use `rvest` to get the `value` attribute of each dropdown and make subsequent `POST`s to the `Detailed_gp.aspx` URL until you've got all the combinations.

You'll probably get a Selenium answer, but this problem only requires posting to forms, which is something `httr` and `rvest` excel at.

Comment: I appreciate the response but I don't really have any background in any of what you mentioned.

Comment: This is an ASP.NET site with event validation and it is not clear on such a site whether what you propose would work. It may work or it may not depending on the backend and what validation is taking place.

Comment: @jdharrison I ran the session through burpsuite (which is why I knew about all the variable names). All you have to do is capture the appropriate initial session variables & hidden form vars and replay them through each `POST`.

Comment: Often the hidden form vars are dynamic and change depending on the current state of the form. Sometimes it is sufficient to use the `__viewstate` and `__eventvalidation` variables initially given. If validation is performed on the backend however this is not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have set up Selenium properly. Make sure you have Selenium downloaded and R Selenium loaded in R. [This link](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/scraping-with-selenium/) might be helpful.

Once Selenium is set up properly, all you have to do is find the css selectors ([selectorgadget](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/) is a great tool for this), and send the required information to the dropdowns, scrape the website and repeat. I would do three dropdowns.